# Trouble Returning Different Variables from Mongo using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

So I have a function that when you pass a username as an argument it queries a MongoDB database and returns the document containing that username. So in the function, I check to see if the document exists containing the username, and if it doesn't I return the document that has an empty string as the username. So kind of like, return default if doesn't exist. So I assume that if it doesn't find a matching document it returns an undefined object.

Ideally, I want a function that when called will either return a default document retrieved from a database when the username doesn't exist or return the corresponding document for the username passed as an argument. Maybe the problems are trying to read or return variables before they exist because of the asynchronous nature of the calls.

I really don't think major restructuring of the code is a good idea, because I'm trying to work with three asynchronous libraries and connect them all together. I have multiple asynchronous classes in recursive processing functions.

```
getContext(username = '') {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tc-db', function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        db.collection('chatters').findOne({ username: username }, function (err, results) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else if (results === undefined) {
            db.collection('chatters').findOne({ username: '' }, function (err, results) {
              console.log('Notifier');
              console.log('Get if Null: ' + JSON.stringify(results));
              return JSON.stringify(results.context);
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Notifier 2');
            return JSON.stringify(results.context);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The actual error I'm getting alot when running the function, especially with a username that doesn't exist in the database is "Can't read property 'context' of null". Thank you guys so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: Your `return` is meaningless.  You should use promises.

Comment: So is there a way where I could still call this function and receive a value back. Could this be done with promises? An example in the context of the code above would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what promises (or callbacks) do.

Comment: Don't I kind of have callbacks in here already. Like where I pass a function into the MongoDB methods. Does the "mongodb" module work with Promises. If so, could someone maybe give a basic example of a function that returns a database object?